# How can i implement value of input like an search?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently facing an issue with setting the value of an input field for search functionality in my React application. I've attempted to achieve this using both state management (useState) and the React hook useRef(), but unfortunately, neither approach seems to be working as expected.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import MovieList from './Components/MovieList';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';

function App() {
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${search}&apikey=a8b01dfe`)
    .then(respone => respone.json())
    .then(json => setData(json.Search))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
 }, [search]);

 const handleSearch = (e) => {
  setSearch(e.target.value);
 }

 return (
   <div>
     <MovieList movie={data}/>
     <NavBar search={handleSearch} />
   </div> 
 );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';

function NavBar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={props.search} type='text' placeholder='Search...'/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Here is how i render movies:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Style/MovieList.css"

function MovieList(props) {
 const item = document.querySelector(".movie-list-main-container");

  window.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) item.scrollLeft += 100;
    else item.scrollLeft -= 100;
  });

  return (
    <div className='movie-list-main-container'>
      {props.movie.map((item, index) => (
        <div className='movies' key={index}><img src={item.Poster} alt={item.Title}/></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MovieList;
```

Comment: Do you call `handleSearch()` anywhere?

Comment: <NavBar search={handleSearch} i'm passing it like prop.

Comment: Yes, you're passing it as a prop, but that doesn't do anything unless you actually use the `search` prop in some way within `NavBar` which you currently aren't doing

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code, to not use a ref, simply pass your handler to be attached to `onChange` prop on the input component

Make sure to pass in the value as a prop in your `NavBar` component

```js
 <NavBar search={handleSearch} searchQuery={search} />
```

```js
import React from 'react';

function NavBar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={props.search} value={props.searchQuery} type='text' placeholder='Search...'/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

#### Suggestion

Make sure to debounce your search (`useEffect`) in `App` component , otherwise you will be spamming the API and doing a search on every key stroke, which will result the API throwing rate limit errors

Here is a nice article on how to debounce https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/debounce-your-search-react-input-optimization-fd270a8042b

Comment: I am very grateful for your response, but it still hasn't solved the problem for me. When I implement the code, I get a blank page and this error in the console. Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at MovieList (MovieList.jsx:17:22)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom_client.js?v=d52fa3fa:12169:26)... But without of that code my page works fine..

Comment: You are trying to render `<MovieList / >` without waiting for the api to fetch data. You need to do the following `{data && <MovieList />}` in your `App` component. This means render the `<MovieList />` component only if there is data, so you won't get the error calling `.map` on undefined. Just to be safe optional chain like this `props?.movie?.map` in movie list . This should be able to fix it

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but this is way how i fix ma issues. I acutally just add an if statment: "useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${search}&apikey=a8b01dfe`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        if (json.Search) {
          setData(json.Search);
        } else {
          setData([]);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, [search]);
"